# What burden resistor value to use for current transformer?

Tags: current, transformer

I'm building a current measuring circuit. The circuit im using is seen below,
[image]

How do I choose the burden resistor for the CT ?

If say im measuring 8A max, then with a 1:1000 CT, thats 8 mA on the secondary. If I want the voltage to be 3.5 V full scale, then R = V/I = 3.5/8mA = 438 ohms ?

Comment: CT datasheets generally give recommended burden ranges. It can be better to use a buffer then amplifier topology to get the output scaling you want, rather than try to achieve it with too high a resistor value which sacrifices linearity.

Comment: is it ok to have -3.5V input?
the datasheet https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/10789fe.pdf specifies input range of 0.03 to 1.8V

Comment: asnwering my own subquestgion above - the abs. input limits are Positive Supply Voltage to  5V Below Negative Supply Voltage. So +/- 3.5V should be ok for for 5V single supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it may be helpful to remember that voltage transformers and current transformers are complimentary.

- Voltage transformers are happy when open-circuit and have a minimum load resistance value (which causes the maximum rated current to flow).
- Current transformers are happy when short-circuited and have a maximum load resistance value (which causes the maximum rated voltage to be generated).

You need to watch a couple of things:

- Your CT will have a maximum "burden" that it can drive. That's the maximum the resistance mentioned above.
- The CT will have a primary rating - the maximum number of ampere-turns it can accept on the primary.
- You need to remember that 8 A is 8 A peak and not 8 A RMS which will result in \$ 8 \sqrt 2 \ \$ A.

> If say im (sic) measuring 8 A max, then with a 1:1000 CT, thats (sic) 8 mA on the secondary.

Correct - but note whether it's peak or RMS.

> If I want the voltage to be 3.5 V full scale, then R = V/I = 3.5/8mA = 438 ohms?

Correct - again subject to peak or RMS.

You probably want to calculate true RMS current so you have a bit of work to do on your sampling and coding.